# Immutable remove object entry react reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutability

I want to immutable remove an object entry in react reducer

```
obj = {
   selections: {}
}
```

this is how i add things to my selections obj

```
return {
  ...state,
  selections: {
    ...state.selections,
    [action.data.type]: action.data
  }
};
```

this will give me

```
selections: {
    test: { some funky data } 
}
```

then when i want to remove test? How do i accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this,

```
this.setState(state => {
   return {
     ...state,
     selections: {
        ...state.selections,
        selections: delete state.selections.test
     }
   }
})
```

Comment: This will just alter selections to true

Answer (score 0):

The best i could do for now is to set it to null

```
return {
  ...state,
  selections: {
    ...state.selections,
    [action.data.type]: null
  }
};
```

its not firing the update when i use Object.assign and using delete

Answer (score 0):

Just copy your state to a temporal variable, then delete the that you don't want:

```
//...
case 'REMOVE_PROPERTY':
  //here we make a copy of selection object, note that this is a shallow copy
  let newSelections = { ...state.selection };
  delete newSelections[action.data.type];
  return {
    ...state,
    //here we overwrite selections object on a new created object before returning the value
    selections: newSelections
};
//...
```

Comment: This will not indicate for react to re-render. It doesnt think its changed

Comment: I'm using this pattern in an [app](https://github.com/ramirozap/agricola-score/blob/master/src/game/players/playersReducer.ts#L21) and works as expected, how is your component connected?

Comment: export connect(
  state => ({
    selections: state.selections
  }),
  dispatch => ({
  })
)(Class));

Comment: here it is a working version, take a look: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-cannon-3en8v?fontsize=14